# ASP.NET core application showing apache default page

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, ubuntu-20.04

I've been following a [blog](https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-web-hosting/how-to-install-an-asp-net-core-in-net-5-app-on-ubuntu-20-04) on how to install ASP.NET Core In .NET 5 App On Ubuntu 20.04. When I visit the link `api.example.com`, it showing default apache page. It should be showing me the ASP.NET Core app.

All the application files are stored in `/var/www/api/` and ownership has been given to `www-data`

**VirtualHost api.conf**

In the VirtualHost I have the following configurations and the conf is enabled.

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost api.example.com:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ServerName api.example.com
    ServerAlias api.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}api-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}api-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

**Add Service**

The following service configuration has been added and service has been enabled.

```
[Unit]
Description=Api

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/api/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/api/Api.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=api
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `sudo systemctl status api.service` I get the following

```
ubuntu@sandbox:~$ sudo systemctl status api.service
● api.service - Api
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/api.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-07-04 12:28:54 UTC; 12h ago
   Main PID: 21133 (dotnet)
      Tasks: 13 (limit: 1116)
     Memory: 33.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/api.service
             └─21133 /usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/api/Api.dll

Jul 04 12:28:55 sandbox api[21133]: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
Jul 04 12:28:55 sandbox api[21133]:       No XML encryptor configured. Key {cb00126e-6ce8-41cc-9568-800ff705be3a} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
Jul 04 12:28:55 sandbox api[21133]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Jul 04 12:28:55 sandbox api[21133]:       Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Jul 04 12:28:55 sandbox api[21133]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Jul 04 12:28:55 sandbox api[21133]:       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Jul 04 12:28:55 sandbox api[21133]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Jul 04 12:28:55 sandbox api[21133]:       Hosting environment: Production
Jul 04 12:28:55 sandbox api[21133]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Jul 04 12:28:55 sandbox api[21133]:       Content root path: /var/www/api
```

Comment: Are you sure you connect unsecure? Some browsers have a tendency to switch your http to https and you don't seem to have a virtual host that matches that. Test from the command line with curl to be sure.

Comment: @rene I have tested through CURL using `curl http://localhost:5000` I got the response of the ASP.NET Core App.

Comment: You need to test `curl http://api.example.com` ...

Comment: @rene - Done. It's giving me that same Apache default page. What does that mean?

Comment: It means your apache virtual host config is not being picked up.

Comment: Your apache log files are empty?

Comment: @rene Yes, both access and error log files are empty

Comment: In all the examples I see here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html they bind to an ip address, not to a domain name. The domain names goes in the `ServerName` setting inside your virtualhost. The ip address is the one found when you run ifconfig.

Comment: @rene It's working now.